# Getting chat history in AIM on Mac

Tags: macos, logging, chat, aim

I need to search through my previous messages or chat conversations I have had with my friends.

I need something like what Gmail gives you, i.e. automatically save all the chats.

Is there a way to do this on AIM on a Mac? I don't want to change the ID because I have already given it to lot of people.

Comment: Is there a dedicated AIM software for mac os or are you talking about adium (pidgin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd venture to guess that most people who use the AIM protocol on the Mac use iChat as their AIM client, not the actual AOL AIM client.  iChat lets you save logs.

iChat > Preferences... > Messages > Save chat transcripts to: *folder*

iChat lets you log in as any AIM ID. It's not like it's limited to mac.com/me.com accounts or anything like that.